# cypress-file-upload do not attach a file to one of the fields

Tags: javascript, cypress, e2e-testing, cypress-file-upload

I'm using `cypress-file-upload` for attaching files to input fields. Using the same approach for all of these inputs in different places *(in different modal windows in my case)*. But in one place files do not attach for some reason, in executed steps file is attached but in modal it isn't shown *(red zone)*.

[image]

What I need to do:

1. open modal
2. attach a file
3. fill all fields
4. click on the Submit button, but it's disabled because fails isn't attached

And how it looks in code:

```
addUpdates(name, family, version, notes, file) {
  cy.get(this.topMenu_addButton).click()
  cy.get('.upload-field').should('be.visible')
  cy.get('input[type=file]').attachFile(file)
  cy.get(this.modal_field).should('be.visible').fill(name)
  cy.get(this.modal_familyField).fill(family)
  cy.get(this.modal_versionField).fill(version)
  cy.get(this.modal_notesField).fill(notes)
  cy.get(this.modal_proceedButton).should('be.enabled').click()
}
```

All fields successfully filled, but file not attached. Any ideas?

Comment: What file type are you trying to attach ?

Comment: @ItsNotAndy `.apk`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The log is telling you the file is actually attached. (Inspect also in dev console, the input element will have a non-empty files array).

It looks like you need to trigger a change or input event to tell the app something has been attached

```js
cy.get('input[type=file]').attachFile(file)
  .trigger('change')
```

or

```js
cy.get('input[type=file]').attachFile(file)
  .trigger('input')
```

Failing that, try to force the button click

```js
cy.get(this.modal_proceedButton).click({force:true})
```

Comment: Thank you, option with `.trigger('input')` forks in my case

Comment: In my case `cy.get('input[type=file]').attachFile('test.txt').trigger('input', {force: true});` worked - since the input was hidden

Comment: This worked for me!

cy.get('input[type=file]').attachFile(file).trigger('change')

Answer (score 3):

This is a custom command that I use to upload files and it has never failed me :)

```
Cypress.Commands.add("UploadFile", function () {
  cy.fixture("somefile", "binary")
  .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
  .then((fileContent) => {
  cy.get('someelement').attachFile({
    fileContent,
    filePath: "somefile",
    fileName: "somefile",
  do more stuff here
   });
  });
 });
```

Think this should work for you

```
addUpdates(name, family, version, notes, file) {
 cy.get(this.topMenu_addButton).click()
 cy.get('.upload-field').should('be.visible')
  cy.fixture("somefile", "binary")
  .then(Cypress.Blob.binaryStringToBlob)
  .then((fileContent) => {
  cy.get('input[type=file]').attachFile({
    fileContent,
    filePath: "somefile",
    fileName: "somefile",
 cy.get(this.modal_field).should('be.visible').fill(name)
 cy.get(this.modal_familyField).fill(family)
 cy.get(this.modal_versionField).fill(version)
 cy.get(this.modal_notesField).fill(notes)
 cy.get(this.modal_proceedButton).should('be.enabled').click()
}
```

Or you can just use the first example I gave as a custom command and do:

```
addUpdates(name, family, version, notes, file) {
  cy.get(this.topMenu_addButton).click()
  cy.get('.upload-field').should('be.visible')
  cy.UploadFile();
  cy.get(this.modal_field).should('be.visible').fill(name)
  cy.get(this.modal_familyField).fill(family)
  cy.get(this.modal_versionField).fill(version)
  cy.get(this.modal_notesField).fill(notes)
  cy.get(this.modal_proceedButton).should('be.enabled').click()
 }
```